# Keep getting same error message trying to load CSV file into R Markdown

Tags: csv, upload, r-markdown

I have tried working this everyway I can think and continue to get the same error message.

```
library(readr)
dailyActivity <- read_csv(".Fitbit Capstone/dailyActivty_merged.csv")
```

/bin/sh: 1: dataset: not found

I did a list files in my console, see results below:

```
list.files()
[1] "Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16"             
[2] "Fitbit Capstone"                           
[3] "Fitbit Tracker Analysis for Bellabeat.Rmd" 
[4] "Fitbit-Tracker-Analysis-for-Bellabeat.html"
[5] "project.Rproj"
```

The file that I am trying to upload is both files 1 and 2.  The Markdown file that I am working in is file 3.  I'm pulling my hair out here.  Any insight anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried several variations of the code below.  With the period at the beginning, without it, with two periods at the beginning.  I have tried going back to where the file is on my computer, where I uploaded it into R in the first place, copied that file path and tried putting that in the code.  It doesn't matter what way I try it, I continue to get the same error code each time.

```
library(readr)
dailyActivity <- read_csv(".Fitbit Capstone/dailyActivty_merged.csv")
```

/bin/sh: 1: dataset: not found

Comment: I could be related to the whitespace between Fitbit and Capstone. And why do you use `.Fitbit` and not only `Fitbit`?

Comment: The one with the .Fitbit was only one of the recent ones I had tried.  Also tried a ..Fitbit from things I saw on other websites.  Tried taking the space out between Fitbit and Capstone but still the same error.  Thanks for ideas though.

Comment: in which folder is your rmd located?

Comment: I have it both on my computer and in R.  In R it is uploaded with this path:     "/cloud/project/dailyActivity_merged.csv"

Comment: I have uploaded it into console, checked the code that was used to upload it, copy and pasted and still get the same error message.  In the environment tab I tried the import data set and copied the code that it put there as well.  It continues to give the same error code,  that the data set is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [package](https://here.r-lib.org/) for relative path reference.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(here)
here::i_am("Fitbit Tracker Analysis for Bellabeat.Rmd")
readr::read_csv(here("Fitbit Capstone", "dailyActivty_merged.csv"))
```
````